# Java | Adding items to List<?>

Tags: java, list, generics, addition

I googled around and I couldn't really understand how to do this. I'm trying to add items to a list like this: `List<?>`. My code looks something like this:

```
public class Test {
    private List<?> list;

    public Test(List<?> useThisList) {
        this.list = useThisList;
    }

    public void add(Object add) {
        this.list.add(add); // this won't compile
    }
}
```

However, as commented, that code won't compile. I've tried to change it to something like:

```
public void add(? add) {
    this.list.add(add);
}
```

But that won't compile for more obvious reasons.
Does anyone know what I need to change this to to make it function properly? Thanks in advance!

By the way, when it does work, you should be able to do this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
new Test(list).add("hello");
```

Comment: Well if you don't know the kind of list you've got, how do you know you can add `add` to it? Perhaps your `Test` class should be generic...

Comment: I would encourage you to read effective java 2nd edition By Joshua Blochs and refer to the item about generics. It gives a handful of insights on how to do a good use of generics / wildcarss

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your `Test` class generic

```
public class Test<E> {
    private List<E> list;

    public Test(List<E> useThisList) {
        this.list = useThisList;
    }

    public void add(E add) {
        this.list.add(add); // this will compile
    }
}
```

Instantiate your test class like this

```
Test<String> t = new Test<String>(new ArrayList<String>());
t.add("Something");
```